# threejs - mapping converted JSON animations to sliders, not fully working

Tags: json, animation, three.js, skinning, collada

I've converted a skinned.dae mesh to JSON using [this loader](http://rmx.github.io/collada-converter/preview/examples/convert.html). I'm now loading it up in a scene and - since its animations are not intended as actual animation, but ranges of motion for model posing, I am attempting to map those animations to sliders. Relevant code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var animation;
loader.load('phases/1/1.json', function(geometry, materials) {
var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));

scene.add(mesh);
console.log(mesh.geometry);
mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
materials.forEach(function(i) { i.skinning = true });

var clip = mesh.geometry.animations[0];
var clip2 = mesh.geometry.animations[1];
var clip3 = mesh.geometry.animations[2];
var clip4 = mesh.geometry.animations[3];
var clip5 = mesh.geometry.animations[4];

mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);

action = mixer.clipAction(clip);
action2 = mixer.clipAction(clip2);
action3 = mixer.clipAction(clip3);
action4 = mixer.clipAction(clip4);
```

I then initialize them:

```
action.play();
action.paused = true;
action2.play();
action2.paused = true;
action3.play();
action3.paused = true;
action4.play();
action4.paused = true;
```

And then in an IIFE create sliders and map said animations:

```
(function() {

var container = document.querySelector('div#sliders'),
slider    = document.createElement('input'),
attrs     = { 'type': 'range', 'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'step': 0.01 };
slider2   = document.createElement('input'),
attrs2    = { 'type': 'range', 'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'step': 0.01 };
slider3   = document.createElement('input'),
attrs3    = { 'type': 'range', 'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'step': 0.01 };
slider4   = document.createElement('input'),
attrs4    = { 'type': 'range', 'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'step': 0.01 };
Object.keys(attrs).forEach(function(i) { slider.setAttribute(i, attrs[i]);});
Object.keys(attrs2).forEach(function(i) { slider2.setAttribute(i, attrs2[i]) });
Object.keys(attrs3).forEach(function(i) { slider3.setAttribute(i, attrs3[i]) });
Object.keys(attrs4).forEach(function(i) { slider4.setAttribute(i, attrs4[i]) });
container.style.position = 'absolute';
container.style.top = '0';
container.style.left = '0';
slider.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
action.time = parseFloat(this.value * action.getClip().duration);
  console.log(action.time);
});
slider2.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
action2.time = parseFloat(this.value * action2.getClip().duration);
});
slider3.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
action3.time = parseFloat(this.value * action3.getClip().duration);
});
slider4.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
action4.time = parseFloat(this.value * action4.getClip().duration);
});

container.appendChild(slider);
container.appendChild(slider2);
container.appendChild(slider3);
container.appendChild(slider4);
}());
```

This works but gives me a surprisingly limited range of motion in each animation - which is to say the animation doesn't play out fully (i.e all keyframes), just tiny movements.

Any ideas why that might be happening? I'm at my wits end.

You can find the live code [here](http://michaelhazani.com/temp/3dgolfer).

Any/all help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set materials after loading to morph yet?

```
for (var m=0; m<materials.length; m++){
    var material = materials[ m ];
    material.morphTargets = true;
}
```

I've gotten this from the json loader example in three.js website and modified it slightly.

hope this helps,
A newb

Comment: It's a skinned mesh, not a morph animation, and the character shows up fine - the problem is one of animation, not materials - I appreciate the attempt, though:)